# How would I add a ajax submit function to a form

Tags: javascript, ajax

I thought this would work, maybe I missed something? What could I do to call a javascropt submit event?

Thanks,

John

```
<html>
<body>
<form name='myForm' action='formprocess.php' method='get'>
Name: <input type='text' onChange="ajaxFunction();" name='username' /> <br />
Time: <input type='text' name='time' />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var frm = $('myform');
    frm.submit(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                alert('ok');
            }
        });

        return preventDefault();
    });
</script>
<div id="box"> </div>
</body>
```

Comment: the onChange function call is from a piece of code before the form (works perfectly)

Comment: submit event on onchange `ajaxFunction()` call?? where is the implementation of `ajaxFunction()`, when are you calling the `submit()`?

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is `name='myForm'`. The name attribute (except for form *controls* (like `<input>`)) is obsolete. Use the `id` attribute instead.

```
id="myForm"
```

The second problem is `$('myform');` which will select `<myform>` elements. Use `#myForm` to select an element by its ID.

The third problem is `return preventDefault();`.

`preventDefault` is a *method* of the event object, not a global, and shouldn't be returned.

You need to capture the event object (it is the first argument to the function) and call the method on it:

```
frm.submit(function (evt) {
    …
    evt.preventDefault();
});
```

Fourth (hat tip to Tieson T.), you need a submit button in the form before you can submit it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, making the edits and I'll let you know :)

Answer (score 0):

`.submit()` doesn't submit a form, but rather adds an event handler to the `onsubmit` event. You still need a submit button. This is untested but should work:

```
<form id="myForm" action='formprocess.php' method='get'>
    Name: <input type='text' onChange="ajaxFunction();" name='username' /> <br />
    Time: <input type='text' name='time' />
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#myform').on('submit', function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            $.get(
                $(this).attr('action'),
                $(this).serialize(),
                function (response, status, jqxhr) {
                    alert('ok');
                }
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```